# What is HALF_EVEN rounding for?

Tags: java, rounding

I can not imagine a situation that I need to use `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` in Java.

What is this rounding mode for?
When do I want to use it?

Please give me some real world examples.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is useful when you are performing multiple rounding operations and want the cumulative result to be a true average, and not skewed up or down, as it would be with HALF_UP or HALF_DOWN.

Specifically, it is useful for statistical analysis (you don't want the results polluted by a non-random averaging system) or any situation where you want random averaging.

Comment: can you explain HALF_UP and HALF_DOWN with an example ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy - If you round 42.5 to the nearest integer, the result is 42. But if you round 43.5 to the nearest integer, the result if 44.

Comment: What Rob described here is half even.

@KPradeepKumarReddy 
Half_down: 43.5 -> 43  
Half_up: 43.5 -> 44   
The latter one is used most of the time and the variant usually tought in schools.

Answer (score 49):

`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` always rounds to the next number, like any other rounding-algorithmn - with only one execption: If the number-to-round is exacly between 2 numbers (2.5, 42.5, -4.5), it will not round it up, but instead round it to the neighbour which is even. Here are some examples:

- 3.2 -> 3
- 3.4 -> 3
- 3.5 -> 4
- 4.5 -> 4
- 5.5 -> 6
- -7.5 -> -8

Comment: This answer explains how _half even_ works, not why you would choose it which is what the question is about.

Comment: Useful in, for example, financial scenarios. If you have a bank account receiving large numbers of deposits of various sizes, and did standard rounding (e.g. 0.5 goes to 1), then there will be a subtle bias to overestimate the total. If you did the converse (0.5 goes to 0), there will be an opposite bias.

By doing the half-even strategy, about half the time you round ".5" up, and half the time down, controlled by the digit before the decimal. You rely on this digit being about half the time even, and half the time odd. Thus it resembles randomness, but is reproducible.

Answer (score 13):

If you have random negative and positive numbers HALF_UP is fine and the net error will tend to 0. HALF_UP is also easier for a human to understand and is often used in finance.

However, if you know you have more of positive (or negative) numbers you will get a bias.  HALF_EVEN and HALF_ODD attempts to correct for this by choosing whether to rounding 0.5 up or down based on whether it is more likely to go to an even or odd number.  This is statistically fairer, provided you have a 50/50 split of even and odd numbers, however harder for a human to understand.

Comment: So, the HALF_EVEN it's only really useful if working with both positive and negative numbers...

Answer (score 11):

The behavior is well described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN):

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" **unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even
>   neighbor**.

So given the number 4.5, which falls right in the middle of the range of numbers between 4 and 5, when you call:

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("4.5").setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

The runtime needs to figure out which neighbor to round too, aka, should it round to 4, or to 5? Normally it would round based on which value 4.5 is closer to, but in this case its close to ***both*** neighbors. Instead of arbitrarily picking the final result though, it picks the even number. This is the behavior of `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. If you wanted to, you could specify `ROUND_HALF_UP` and the final result would have been 5, and not 4. Also, keep in mind that the determination about how to round is based on what the final result would be (and not on the decimal portion of the big decimal, as you seem to have assumed).

Comment: This is a really good explanation as to what ROUND_EVEN actually does. Complement with a real world example and this is the best answer in the thread.

Answer (score 4):

Referring [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) says:

```
Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both
```

neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

Behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the
discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's
even. Note that this is the rounding mode that statistically minimizes
cumulative error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations.
It is sometimes known as "Banker's rounding," and is chiefly used in the
USA. This rounding mode is analogous to the rounding policy used for float
and double arithmetic in Java.

```
Example:

Input ->    rounded  
5.5   ->    6  
2.5   ->    2  
1.6   ->    2  
1.1   ->    1  
1.0   ->    1  
-1.0  ->    -1  
-1.1  ->    -1  
-1.6  ->    -2  
-2.5  ->    -2  
-5.5  ->    -6
```

So it rounds towards nearest value and if both are equidistant then it rounds towards an even number.