# DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

Tags: java, decimal

`DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");` giving me unexpected result for the below values:

```
for value 0.005 = 0.00
          0.015 = 0.02
```

DecimalFormat  is not formatting the `0.005 to 0.01`. Please let me know how to get the value of `0.005 to 0.01` when `DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");` is provided.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use Match.round(val) and then apply DecimalFormat

Comment: Add the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: double d= 0.005;
  DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  double twoDecimal =  Double.parseDouble(newFormat.format(d));
  System.out.println(twoDecimal);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching your comment, you can manually round to 2 digit and then do Decimal Format.

Here is the example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input = 0.004;
    DecimalFormat formatter = getDecimalFormat(input); 
    System.out.println(formatter.format(round2Digit(input)));
    input = 0.005;
    formatter = getDecimalFormat(input); 
    System.out.println(formatter.format(round2Digit(input)));
    input = 0.015;
    formatter = getDecimalFormat(input); 
    System.out.println(formatter.format(round2Digit(input)));
}

private static DecimalFormat getDecimalFormat(double input){
    DecimalFormat formatter = (input % 1 == 0) ? new DecimalFormat("##.##"): new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); 
    return formatter;
}

private static double round2Digit(double input){
    double result = input * 100;
    result = Math.round(result);
    result = result / 100;
    return result;
}
```

Output:

> 0.00
>
> 0.01
>
> 0.02

Comment: if we use roundingMode.Up it will give output of  0.004 as 0.001.

Comment: Could you check the answer now?

Comment: thanks for the answer. if its possible can you please let me know why DecimalFormat  was behaving like this?

Comment: By default DecimalFormat uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN. It round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134938/what-is-half-even-rounding-for for more info.