# How to use decimal format to hide trailing zero only in integer numbers

Tags: java, kotlin, double, decimalformat

I need format numbers like this:

```
23.0 -> 23
23.20 -> 23.20
23.00 -> 23
23.11 -> 23.11
23.2 -> 23.20
23.999 -> 24
23.001 -> 23
1345.999 -> 1346 // Edited the question to add this from the OP's comment
```

Here is my code:
java:

```
  public static String toPrice(double number) {
         DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##", formatSymbols);
            return format.format(number);
    
         }
```

kotlin:

```
fun Double.toPrice(): String =   DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##", DecimalFormatSymbols().apply {
                groupingSeparator = ' '
            }).format(this)
```

But for input 23.20 or 23.2 I get the result 23.2. This is wrong for me. I need 23.20. Which string pattern should I use to achieve this result? Please, help me.

Comment: You are using the term "pattern" incorrectly. In programming, design patterns are very specific examples of solutions to specific problems. You just need a bit of help with formatting, though I think you're wrong. Displaying a number as 21.00 is saying that you know the number to a higher precision than a number you display as just 21.

Comment: @NomadMaker The `DecimalFormat` class refers to its string template as a ‘pattern’ throughout; the constructor parameter in this case is called `pattern`.  So it seems perfectly reasonably to call it that.  (Design patterns aren't the only sort of pattern.)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash What you said is not correct. The (my) answer on the linked question produces `23.20` for an input of `23.20`, and satisfies all the other examples too. It's very similar to Cenfracee's answer here. This question is a duplicate except for specifically mentioning `DecimalFormat`. I think `DecimalFormat` is not the right tool or the job here, `String.format()` is much simpler.

Comment: Oh, the question was re-opened. Here's the duplicate: [Print float with two decimals unless number is a mathematical integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64102602/print-float-with-two-decimals-unless-number-is-a-mathematical-integer).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It's difficult to reply when you delete your comments. In the case of `23.001`, the answer on the above post will produce `23`, which is what was required.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip - I had reopened it based on my initial analysis. On further analysis, I found that you are right. I've closed it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

In case you need to format `1345.999` as `1346` (as mentioned in your comment), you can do so by adding a couple of extra steps in the original answer:

1. Format the number with the pattern, `#,###,###.00` and then remove all commas so that it can be parsed back to double.
2. Parse the converted string into `double` and follow the rest of the solution as mentioned in the original answer.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.0));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.20));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.01));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.00));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1345.999));
    }

    static String getFromattedNumber(double number) {
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
        double num = Double.parseDouble(format.format(number).replace(",", ""));

        // Format for integer decimal numbers
        NumberFormat formatInt = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");

        if ((int) num == num) {
            return formatInt.format(number);
        } else {
            return format.format(number);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1,234,567
1,234,567.20
1,234,567.01
1,234,567
1,346
```

### Original answer

You will need to use two formats as shown below:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.0));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.20));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.01));
        System.out.println(getFromattedNumber(1234567.00));
    }

    static String getFromattedNumber(double number) {
        // Format for integer decimal numbers
        NumberFormat format1 = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");

        // Format for non-integer decimal numbers
        NumberFormat format2 = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");

        if ((int) number == number) {
            return format1.format(number);
        } else {
            return format2.format(number);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1,234,567
1,234,567.20
1,234,567.01
1,234,567
```

Comment: DecimalFormat by default  uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN (as I need)
And for example when my value is  1345.999 I get result 1 346.00 (two zeroes at the end, incorrect)

Comment: @testovtest - `1346.00` is the correct result by using `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28134961/10819573) for an explanation. In case you need `1345.999` to be formatted as `1345.99`, use `RoundingMode.FLOOR`.

Comment: For input 1345.999 I need output 1346 (rounded but without zeroes at the end)

Comment: @testovtest - I've posted an update to fulfil this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 5):

```java
public static String toPrice(double number) {
    if (number == (int) number) {
        return Integer.toString((int) number);
    } else {
        return String.format("%.2f", number);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
To include thousand separator

```java
public static String toPrice(double number) {
    if (number == (int) number) {
        return String.format("%,d",(int)number);
    } else {
        return String.format("%,.2f", number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need display price with thousand separators

Comment: Check the edited answer